# Removing ripples from PWM controlled LED in camera vision application

Tags: led, pwm, camera, ripple

I have made a camera vision setup with highpower LED's which are controlled with a simple NE555 timer and a mosfet. The LED system is lighting up an area where a camera is looking, but unfortunately i am experiencing ripples/stripes on the video stream due to the nature of the PWM dimmer. Is there a way to reduce these stripes or even eliminate them?

The camera: http://charmedlabs.com/default/?page_id=211

NE555 circuit:

[image]

Comment: TRy changing the 100N on pin 6&2 to ground to 10N or other values. Higher and different frequencies may help.

Comment: Try frequencies twice, three times or more than the frequency of the capturing camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used an inductor (with maybe a capacitor) filter in line with the LEDs you would get much lower ripple voltage on the LEDs. At the moment it sounds like the LEDs are being modulated directly by the PWM frequency and this will generate "beats" with the video frame and line rate. This produces ripples in the same way as aliasing can occur when sampling a frequency that is too high. You could also try increasing the PWM frequency or maybe locking it to the video signal somehow.

Here's a circuit that does this: -

[image]

By the way the circuit link doesn't work for me.

Comment: Whats mostly important is somehow killing the ripples or beats as i am not able to do much on the camera side. Is it possible to adjust the current on this application circuit as i only see permanent resistors. Cheers.

Comment: Yes by changing the current feedback (Rsense) This cct regulates the current == brightness. Your 555timer circuit could be changed todo a similar thing by placing an inductor in series with the LED's (and providing an additional freewheel diode)

Comment: @JavaCake I still can't view your circuit for some reason. The circuit I've shown is an example of using an inductor/capacitor to reduce ripple. I expect you can use it but you'll have to read the data sheet. I also expect that increasing your PWM frequency will help a lot too.

Comment: @Andyaka the OP is showing up fine here. You may have some browser or proxy specific block: http://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Vkw.gif

Comment: @JonRB thanks for that - looks like my end is at fault!

Comment: The only problem with increasing my PWM frequency will be an unnecessary change in brightness as i actually need it to stay at the current brightness its set to. So my question is how i exactly measure the right inductor size?

Comment: Using a filter to (effectively) get a DC level out of PWM defeats a large part of the purpose of PWM - high current in the load.  It might be appropriate in this case because of the camera issue, but unless you're intentionally building a DAC then it's a bad approach.

Comment: @markt - I fail to see your concern - an inductor capacitor filter will work efficiently and effectively unless you are aware of something I'm unaware of?

Comment: @JavaCake - why does increasing the PWM frequency affect brightness - it's the duty cycle that sets brightness.

Comment: Filtering the PWM turns it into a DAC. At low duty cycles the DAC output will be too low to forward bias the LED.

Comment: @markt that's true but in my defence I'm recommending the constant current circuit in my answer.